# simple Google Search using python

Tags: python

Hi all I am new to python,
I am trying to create a simple google search tool which asks user for

-> search category and

-> search term

the search category is a ipython widget drop down list whose 'options' contains a dictionary

```
{"All": "", "Image":"tbm=isch&", "Video":"tbm=vid&", "Books":"tbm=bks&"}
```

the 'values' of the dictionary is inserted into google url so that the google search page is opened under the selected category directly

my code:

```
import webbrowser
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display


def google_search():

# declaring dropdown object as dd
    dd = widgets.Dropdown(
        options = {"All": "", "Image":"tbm=isch&", "Video":"tbm=vid&", "Books":"tbm=bks&"},
        value = "")


    def on_change(change):
        if change['type'] == 'change' and change['name'] == 'value':
            dd.value = change['new']
            print(dd.value)



    hb = widgets.HBox([widgets.Label(value="Select Search Category: "),dd])



    display(hb)


    srch_term = input("Enter Search Term: ")

    dd.observe(on_change)

    url = f'http://www.google.com/search?{dd.value}q={srch_term}'

    print(url)

    webbrowser.open(url)


google_search()
```

output:

```
Select Search Category: Video

Enter Search Term: ki
http://www.google.com/search?q=ki
tbm=vid&
```

I am confused with the output as the print(dd.value) of the on_change(change) is executed after the print(url) despite the print(dd.value) getting executed using dd.observe(on_change) which is before print(url) statement

can you please help me point out the mistake??

Answer (score 0):

This probably has to do with `input()` being blocking.

An alternative solution which uses a text widget instead:

```
import webbrowser
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

# declaring dropdown object as dd
dd = widgets.Dropdown(
    options={"All": "", "Image": "tbm=isch", "Video": "tbm=vid", "Books": "tbm=bks"},
    value="")

hb = widgets.HBox([widgets.Label(value="Select Search Category: "), dd])

def on_change(change):
    if change['type'] == 'change' and change['name'] == 'value':
        dd.value = change['new']

dd.observe(on_change)

tw = widgets.Text(
    value='Hello World',
    placeholder='Enter Search Term',
    disabled=False
)

def search(tw):
    url = f'http://www.google.com/search?q={tw.value}&{dd.value}'
    webbrowser.open(url)


tw.on_submit(search)

display(hb, tw)
```

Comment: Thank you Elar for your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ELAR I have modified the code which is working perfectly fine.

this new code is very simple without dd.observe and confusing steps under on_change(change) function.

my modified code:

```
import webbrowser
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display


def google_search():

    lbl = widgets.Label(value="Select Search Category: ",
                    layout=widgets.Layout(width='20%', height='40px'))

    dd = widgets.Dropdown(
            options = {"All": "", "Image":"tbm=isch&", "Video":"tbm=vid&", "Books":"tbm=bks&"},
            value = "",
            layout=widgets.Layout(width='10%', height='28px'))


    txt_box = widgets.Text(placeholder = 'Enter Search Term',
                           disabled = False,
                           layout=widgets.Layout(width='40%', height='50px'))



    hb1 = widgets.HBox([lbl, dd, txt_box])

    display(hb1)


    def on_change(change):
        url = f'http://www.google.com/search?{hb1.children[1].value}q={hb1.children[2].value}'
        webbrowser.open(url)


    hb1.children[2].on_submit(on_change)
```

Mistakes I have made in the code posted in the question:

1. Using `input()` to retrieve search term entered by user. As rightly suggested by ELAR it was blocking the value from the dropdown widget to be inserted into URL variable. Using text widget instead to get and insert the search term was super easy. Thank you once again Elar.
2. I was also directly accessing drop down value`(dd.value)`. After solving other widget exercise I learnt that to access a widget value where the widget(in this case drop down) is inside a HBox or VBox widget I need to specify the children index of that widget in the widget box and .value attached to it.
   eg.
   in my answer code dd(drop down widget object) is children # 2 in hb1(horizontal box widget)
   so to access value of dd use

   hb1.children[1].value

Answer (score 0):

Below Python code will return the Google Search Result. Just copy and paste the code on your editor and use get_gse(query) function for google search : get_gse("ameriaca")

Note : You have to install Some Python libraries for this python code : BeautifulSoup, requests, json and lxml, Happy Coding :)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, json, lxml
def get_gse(query):
    headers = {
        'User-agent':
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582'
    }

    params = {
        'q': query,  # query
        'gl': 'us',  # country to search from
        'hl': 'en',  # language
    }

    html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", headers=headers, params=params)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

    data = {'title':[],'link':[],'snippet':[]}
    #
    for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc'):
        title = result.select_one('.DKV0Md').text
        link = result.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']

        # sometimes there's no description and we need to handle this exception
        try:
            snippet = result.select_one('#rso .lyLwlc').text
        except:
            snippet = None

        # data.append({
        #     'title': title,
        #     'link': link,
        #     'snippet': snippet,
        # })
        data['title'].append(title)
        data['link'].append(link)
        data['snippet'].append(snippet)

    # return (json.dumps(data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
    return data 
output = get_gse("america")
print(output)
```

Output :

```json
{
  "title": [
    "United States - Wikipedia",
    "Americas - Wikipedia",
    "AMERICA | Official Website Featuring Gerry Beckley and ...",
    "American Airlines - Airline tickets and cheap flights at aa.com",
    "United States | History, Map, Flag, & Population | Britannica",
    "Bank of America - Banking, Credit Cards, Loans and Merrill ...",
    "America Magazine | The Jesuit Review of Faith & Culture"
  ],
  "link": [
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States",
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americas",
    "https://www.venturahighway.com/",
    "https://www.aa.com/homePage.do",
    "https://www.britannica.com/place/United-States",
    "https://www.bankofamerica.com/",
    "https://www.americamagazine.org/"
  ],
  "snippet": [
    "The United States of America (U.S.A. or USA), commonly known as the United States (U.S. or US) or America, is a country primarily located in North America.",
    "In modern English, North and South America are generally considered separate continents, and taken together are called the Americas, or more rarely America.",
    "VenturaHighway.com - official home of music group America featuring Gerry Beckley and Dewey Bunnell and songs Horse with No Name, Sister Golden Hair,\xa0...",
    "American Airlines has airline tickets, cheap flights, vacation packages and American Airlines AAdvantage bonus mile offers at aa.com.",
    "2 days ago — United States, country in North America that is a federal republic of 50 states. Besides the 48 conterminous states that occupy the middle\xa0...",
    "What would you like the power to do? For you and your family, your business and your community. At Bank of America, our purpose is to help make financial\xa0...",
    "Latest from America. January 03, 12:20 pm. The poor have been hard hit by Covid-19. Now inflation is pushing some to the brink. By J.D. Long-García."
  ]
}
```